# Building Dart on Mac: "xcodebuild: error: 'dart.xcodeproj' does not exist."

Tags: build, compiler-errors, dart, xcode5

I think I've done all the steps I'm supposed to build Dart (at least twice, in fact), but I get this:

```
$ ./tools/build.py --arch=ia32
xcodebuild -project dart.xcodeproj -target All -configuration DebugIA32 SYMROOT=/Users/eric/lib/dart/dart/xcodebuild
Build settings from command line:
    SYMROOT = /Users/eric/lib/dart/dart/xcodebuild

xcodebuild: error: 'dart.xcodeproj' does not exist.
BUILD FAILED
```

Indeed, I don't see a `dart.xcodeproj` anywhere on my system. As far as I know, I haven't done anything weird. Any ideas?

EDIT: I've run

```
$ gclient config http://dart.googlecode.com/svn/branches/bleeding_edge/deps/standalone.deps
$ gclient sync
$ gclient runhooks
```

which seems like all that's supposed to be necessary. (I've also tried it with `all.deps` instead of `standalone.deps`.)

Comment: You might want to do 'all' - gclient config http://dart.googlecode.com/svn/branches/bleeding_edge/deps/all.deps

Comment: Thanks - I did try that too (which I mentioned above, not very visibly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally gleaned from [this page](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/Clang) that the problem is that `dart.xcodeproj` doesn't get built unless `GYP_GENERATORS` is set to `xcode`, e.g.:

```
$ export GYP_GENERATORS=xcode
$ gclient runhooks
```

After that, `tools/build.py` succeeds.

Or, it can probably be built using `ninja` by building with something along the lines of

```
$ ninja -C out/Debug dart
```

although that didn't work out super well for me (I just guessed at the command line arguments).

Answer (score 0):

Have you ran gclient sync & gclient runhooks?

This does the work to generate the proj files.

See https://code.google.com/p/dart/wiki/GettingTheSource

Comment: Yep. I have. I'll note the steps I did in the question.